# What are the configureMessageBroker and registerStompEndpoints methods in the websocket for?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, websocket, spring-websocket

I started to learn the Websocket from the guide on the spring website, and there was such a code in the websocket config class

```
@Override
public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
    config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
    config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
}

@Override
public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
    registry.addEndpoint("/gs-guide-websocket").withSockJS();
}
```

Specifically, I did not understand what endPoint is and why it is needed, I did not find any clear explanations on the Internet, or I am very stupid to understand them.

More questions about the methods setApplicationDestinationPrefixes and
enableSimpleBroker.

As I understand it, the first one is needed in order to be able to send messages only to an address with the prefix "/topic". And the second method is for @MessageMapping to process only those messages that have the prefix "/app". I would like to know if I understood everything correctly. And can I also change the value of "/app" to any other ? because when I changed it, the application stopped working. Thanks in advance to everyone who will help! :)

Answer (score 1):

In my understanding registerStompEndpoints is where you specify your primary route for WebSocket communication to be listened by the server (You can think of this as a servlet context that we provide for your application in Spring context )

ConfigureMessageBroker is where you define your prefix for the topic but people keep it as "/topics" to make more sense out of it (In a spring MVC context you can string as the root path of a controller)

I created an example some time ago, it will help you clear up some confusion, if you want to have a look it's here:

https://github.com/sydkaz/films/blob/master/client/src/film/FilmList.js